# Bind a TextBox to a Dictionary's Keys

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

I'm currently using MVVM Light Toolkit and creating an application in WPF C#. I currently have a ComboBox in my XAML like so:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="367,39,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" ItemsSource="{Binding Combo_Major_Commands}"/>
```

And in the code:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _combo_Major_Commands;
public Dictionary<string, string> Combo_Major_Commands
{
    get { return _combo_Major_Commands; }
    private set;
}
```

Now in my runtime code I initialize it and add the items I need like so:

```
_combo_Major_Commands = new Dictionary<string, string>();
_combo_Major_Commands.Add("Standby", "STBY");
_combo_Major_Commands.Add("Operate", "OPER");
_combo_Major_Commands.Add("Remote", "REMOTE");
_combo_Major_Commands.Add("Local", "LOCAL");
```

Is there any way to bind my ComboBox to just the key values? Currently it binds to the entire value and shows the following

```
[Standby, STBY]
```

In the combobox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set which part of `KeyValuePair` you want to display by setting `DisplayMemberPath` on `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox ... ItemsSource="{Binding Combo_Major_Commands}" DisplayMemberPath="Key"/>
```